# Page Redirect in SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, redirect

How would I be able to redirect someone to a specific page based on their user profile information such as the department they are in?

I came up with 2 options:

1. Have a "My Department" link to a aspx page that uses SharePoint's object model to determine what department they are and then redirect based on their department.
2. Have an HTTPModule redirect the user after performing the user profile check.

Number 2 seems dumb, since it means we will be checking for every link we click.

Number 1 seems possible.

Is there a better way to redirect a user to a page based on their profile data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with number 1. You could even make a user control that calculates the link ahead of time and cache it per user to reduce load.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Liam Cleary's blog, he has written and published a pretty sophisticated web part that does some of this:
http://www.helloitsliam.com/archive/2008/07/15/redirect-web-part-update.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to show personalized content?  If so and you are using MOSS have you thought about using Audiences?